# Ubuntu 13.10 "Timeout was reached" when "Browse Network" selected

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, ubuntu-13.10

I've been having this problem since around 12.04.  I just did a fresh install of 13.10 with a dual boot of Windows 7 and the problem still exists.

1. Open Nautilus File Explorer.
2. Select "Browse Network" in the bottom left corner
3. The system will hang for about 20 seconds and it will finally come back and say

> **Oops!  Something went wrong.**
>  
>   Unhandled error message: Timeout was reached

If I wait about 10 seconds and press Browse Network again, it will work fine the second time in.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the [global] section of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
netbios name = <hostname>
name resolve order = bcast host
```

Then either restart the smbd and nmbd services or reboot the system.

You should now be able to browse the network shares.

Comment: Thank you!   This worked for me.  In the end, I didn't use the "netbios name = <hostname>" line. I read somewhere that Samba will use the system hostname if "netbios name" isn't specified so it didn't seem necessary.  The real key was getting "bcast" before "host".  I already had a  "; name resolve order" line in the smb.conf file, so I just rearranged the order of the strategies.  I ended up with "name resolve order = lmhosts bcast host wins" (no semi-colon) as the final fix.  Thank you again.